# Is it possible to configure .Net Core to use the file system to cache responses?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware

**Specifically, is there any way in .Net Core (3.0 or earlier) to use the local file system as a Response Cache instead of just in-memory?**

After a fair amount of researching, the closest thing seems to be the Response Caching middleware [1], but this does not:

1. allow pages to be cached indefinitely,
2. preserve caches between application and server restarts,
3. allow invalidating the cache on a per-page basis (e.g. blog entry updated),
4. allow invalidating the entire cache when global changes are made (e.g. theme update, menu changes, etc.).

I'm guessing these features will require custom implementation of ResponseCaching that hits the local file system, but I don't want to reinvent it if it already exists.

### Some background:

This will replace our use of a static site-generator, which is problematic for site-wide changes because of the sheer quantity of data (nearly 24 hours to generate and copy to all of the servers).

The scenario is very similar to an encyclopedia or news site -- the vast majority of the content changes infrequently, a few things are added per day, and there is no user-specific content (and if or when there is, it would be dynamically loaded via JS/Ajax).  Additionally, the page loads happen to be processor/memory/database intensive.

We will be using a reverse proxy like CloudFlare or AWS CloudFront, but AWS automatically expires their edge caches daily.  Edge node cache misses are still frequent.

This is different than IDistributedCache [2] in that it should be response caching, not just caching data used by the MVC Model.

We will also use in-memory cache [3], but again, that solves a different caching scenario.

#### References

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed

[3] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. It may help you understand why you got downvoted, and why there are close votes for this post. This post is off-topic in the fact that you are asking for a library recommendation. Also, you posted this once, [deleted it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55659570/net-core-middleware-to-cache-pages-via-the-file-system), and then posted it again, which is annoying.

Comment: @R.Richards - Thank you for the explanation. After revising the question a number of times, it seemed to be different enough to warrant a different question, but I will certainly avoid doing so in the future. Ultimately, I would like to use "just .Net Core," and in a way that is very similar to the functionality that one gets out-of-the-box. In fact, it's quite possible that they provide that functionality with just a flag which I have been unable to find. The term "library" was arguably misplaced. Thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Extensions/
https://github.com/speige/AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Extensions

Doesn't support .net core 3 yet though.

Answer (score -1):

Currently (April 2019) the answer appears to be: **no**, there is nothing out-of-the-box for this.

There are three viable approaches to accomplish this using .Net Core:

1. Fork the built-in ResponseCaching middleware and create a flag for cache-to-disk:

   https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Middleware/ResponseCaching

   This might be annoying to maintain because the namespaces and class names will collide with the core framework.
2. Implement this missing feature in EasyCaching, which apparently already has caching to disk on their radar:

   https://github.com/dotnetcore/EasyCaching/blob/master/ToDoList.md

   A pull request may be more likely accepted, since it's a planned feature.
3. There is apparently a port of Strathweb.CacheOutput to .Net Core, which would allow one to implement IApiOutputCache to save to disk:

   https://github.com/Iamcerba/AspNetCore.CacheOutput#server-side-caching

Although this question is about caching within .Net Core using the local file system, this could also be accomplished using a local instance of Sqlite on each server node, and then configuring EasyCaching for response caching and to point it to the Sqlite instance on localhost.

I hope this helps someone else who finds themselves in this scenario!